# How to place a shapefile on top of raster file in one plot, and then save the plot in a Jpeg file format

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, rasterio, earthpy

*I am posting this question after three days searching the net but no success. Hope can get the answer here. Please do NOT delete the post as I did not find an answer for it here also. Thanks.*

I have 2 files:

1. A raster image file (i.e., Air temperature 2020-01-01.tif)
2. World countries boundary shapefile ((i.e., World_Countries_base_map.shp)

**Goal:** I want to plot the shapefile on top of raster file, and then save the plot in a Jpeg file format to get something like this eventually:

[image]

I am quite new in Python, and used Spyder to prepare this simple code to do so:

```
# Import needed packages
import os
import rasterio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import earthpy as et
from matplotlib import pyplot

## list all raster images in tiff format in the folder:
list_files = [f for f in 
       os.listdir('C:/Users/Desktop/Question/Raster_Air_temp') 
       if '.tif' in f]
print(list_files[1])  # checking the 1st file in the list

## reading the first tiff file:    
raster_image = rasterio.open(list_files[1])

## plot it
draft_output = pyplot.imshow(raster_image.read(1), cmap='jet')

## importing world shapefile
World_map = gpd.read_file('C:/Users/Desktop/Question/World_shapefile/World_Countries_base_map.shp')

# plot World shapefile
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (30,30))  # image size and quality can be controled by figsize
ax.set_title('The Glob Map', fontsize=50); 
World_map.plot(ax=ax, color='white', edgecolor='black')     # colors note at  https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html
plt.show()

## Plot both World shapefile and raster image in one graph:

????
```

[image]

However, this code just produces **2 separated plots** in the console for me as can be seen above.

**Question**: How can I type a proper code in ???? section of the code to get to my Goal (mentioned above)?
Thanks to all comments and helps.

Here, I share the two files in order to make it easier for those who want help.
[Download the files from my Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9uzhi6q7gdfilx2/Shapefile_and_Raster_file.zip?dl=0)

.

Answer (score 4):

since i have no access to your data I am showing the principle with some sample data from geopandas and a random numpy ndarray as a tiff surrogate.

the key point is to show the tiff with rasterios rasterplot and don't forget to set the extent of your DEM!

[image]

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np
from rasterio import plot as rasterplot
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


# this is how you'd open the raster dataset if you have one
#tiff = rasterio.open('example.tif')
#tiff_extent = [tiff.bounds[0], tiff.bounds[2], tiff.bounds[1], tiff.bounds[3]]

# i am making this array up
tiff_band_1 = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(65, 64))
tiff_extent = [4159200.0, 4808100.0, 2828000.0, 3482600.0]

shapefile = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
shapefile = shapefile.to_crs('epsg:3035')
shapefile = shapefile[shapefile.name == 'Germany']

f, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot DEM
rasterplot.show(
    tiff_band_1,  # use tiff.read(1) with your data
    extent=tiff_extent,
    ax=ax,

)
# plot shapefiles
shapefile.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.savefig('test.jpg')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It worked perfectly fine for me 
But it doesn't actually save the image which I think can be done using some matplotlib function that can save the plot as an image.

Thanks