# Plot geopandas dataframe on top of raster using matplotlib/gdal(numpy)/geopandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, gdal, rasterio

I want to plot my geopandas objects on top of a raster. Other people have asked this question here before and all answers seems to be:

convert numpy array(raster) into Rasterio object.

Is there a solution to plot this without Rasterio? Seems crazy that I need to convert my gdal object into Rasterio just to plot it?

Comment: there are lots of examples on stackoverflow and in docs showing how to plot a numpy array (lots of ways) and also how to plot a geodataframe. just use the same matplotlib axis object. for anything more detailed we'll need to know more about what exactly you're trying to do, and what you've tried.

Comment: You don't need to use RasterIO for something like that.

Comment: e.g.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61980063/python-how-to-place-a-shapefile-on-top-of-raster-file-in-one-plot-and-then-sa/70297437#70297437